# Read DbContextOptions value in Entity Framework core constructor

Tags: entity-framework-core, connection-string, dbcontext

In my asp.net core service, I have this in the startup

```
services.AddDbContext<Mydb_Context>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Settings:ConnString"]));
```

and to make it works, I created also this snippet:

```
public Mydb_Context(DbContextOptions<Mydb_Context> options) : base(options)
{
    //other stuff here
}
```

My problem now is: in "other stuff here" section, how can I read the options value and retrieve my connection string? Since there another dll and not the same project, I can't just read it again from the appsettings.json.

If I break my code during a debug session, I can see the connection string in the value inside this object, but I don't know how to get it properly. I see this value inside the "Extension" attribute of the options object.

So, how can I read the DbContextOptions value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, how can I read the DbContextOptions value?

You can (not publicly but using some EF Core internal infrastructure objects, in particular [`RelationalOptionsExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaloptionsextension?view=efcore-2.0) class), but you don't need to.

To get the connection information, simply use context [`Database`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.database?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Database) property and [`GetDbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getdbconnection?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_GetDbConnection_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_) method:

```
public Mydb_Context(DbContextOptions<Mydb_Context> options) : base(options)
{
    //other stuff here
    var connectionString = this.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
}
```